# How to replace string for multiple lines in react js

Tags: reactjs, replace, tags

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku2uM.jpg) Here i want to replace Special characters"E" with
"bold tag" but it is changing only in one line i want to replace for
all the lines which contains special character E & F please verify the
screenshot for the reference

```
import React from 'react'; import '../screens/MainScreen.css'; import
{ FaArrowRight } from 'react-icons/fa';


export default function MainScreen() {
    // let formData = newFormData();

     const onFileChange = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const exampleFileReader = new FileReader()
    exampleFileReader.onload = async (e) => { 
      var text = (e.target.result)
      var result =  text.replace("\u001bE","<b>").replace('\u001bF','</b>').replace('\u001b-1','<u>').replace('\u001b-0','</u>');
      console.log(result,"result")
    };
    exampleFileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0])   };


  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <img src={Pic} style={{ width: '120px', height: '100px', marginTop: '40px' }} />
        <h1 style={{
          color: 'red', fontSize: 50,
          textAlign: 'center', border: '1px solid green', width: '40%'
        }}>Text to PDF Converter</h1>
      </center>
      <div className="container">
        <input type="file" multiple={true} style={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor: "green", padding: 10, fontSize: 20, width: '20%',
paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 20 }}
          onChange={(e)=>onFileChange(e)} />
        <FaArrowRight size={50} color='red' />
        <h1 style={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor: "red", padding: 10, fontSize: 20, width: '20%', paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 20 }}
>Convert</h1>
        <FaArrowRight size={50} color='green' />
        <h1 style={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor: "green", padding: 10, fontSize: 20, width: '20%', paddingTop: 20,
paddingBottom: 20 }}>PDF Download</h1>
      </div>
    </div>   ) };
```

Answer (score 0):

e.target.result is probably not correct, please console.log it and post the general e.target in order to help you better (try this)

```
const onFileChange = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
const exampleFileReader = new FileReader()
exampleFileReader.onload = async (e) => { 
  var text = (e.target.value)
  var result =  text.replace("\u001bE","<b>").replace('\u001bF','</b>').replace('\u001b-1','<u>').replace('\u001b-0','</u>');
  console.log(result,"result")
};
exampleFileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0])   };
```